# User Profile Disks not created - 2012R2 pooled VDI windows 7 VM

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, rds, vdi

Servers-

- RD Web Access/Connection Broker - VMWare 2012R2 machine - VDW
- RD Virtualization Hosts - 2x physical servers - VD1/VD2

The User_Profile storage location is a replicated DFS on the F drive of VD1/VD2 called user_profiles.  It is DFS replicated and namespaced (\domain\user_profiles), however due to VDI/DFS issues it is referenced to just one server as a normal shared drive in the VDI settings (\VD1\User_profiles).  I have also tried setting this up on a non-DFS shared folder and get the same error.

Permissions for the folder are set to:

- Share permissions are R/W to VDW/VD1/VD2 and admin groups
- Security permissions are Full Control to VDW/VD1/VD2 and admin groups

The UVHD-template.vhdx is created and no errors are thrown.  **When logging into a new VM, no vhdx is created for the user profile disk** and a few errors are logged:

VM Host Server:

- Warning: Remote Desktop Services has taken too long to load the user configuration from server \MSSG.domain for user adminuser (note not the user that logged in to the VM, but the user that is logged into the server itself.  Happens everytime the VM is logged into though)
- Error: Driver HP Color LaserJet 4700 required for printer !!print2k.domain!PRINT2K-12518 is unknown. Contact the administrator to install the driver before you log in again.
  (a couple more of the same error for different printers)

VM:

- Warning: The client computer does not support RemoteFX. The connection will be made with the RDP Graphics. The relevant status code was 0x10a.
- Error: Windows has backed up this user profile. Windows will automatically try to use the backup profile the next time this user logs on.
- Error: Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.
  Warning:
  The client computer does not support RemoteFX. The connection will be made with the RDP Graphics. The relevant status code was 0x10a.

Any help is appreciated.  We were looking forward to UPD, however after more research and working with it it's feeling like a nightmare.  If we should be looking at an alternative solution please let me know.

Comment: this smells like a permissions problem, what are the permissions on the folder containing the profile disks?

Comment: Edited it with permissions. Had a lot of issues with that originally, but it always threw an error when trying to apply the user profile disk settings in server manager.

Comment: That is to say it always threw an error in server manager until it created the UVHD_template.  Would the users potentially need permission there?  Is the hyper-v running on a special user?  I haven't found any documentation that suggests this is an issue.

Comment: something is definitely wrong with permissions, it should have automatically added the session host account with full control when you added the user profile share.  you should not have to manually add anything other than everyone read (the default share permission) when you create the share

Comment: So I made a new folder this morning, set everyone to read on the share.  No go.  Set the VDW to R/W on the share and it worked.  It added in the VD2 account (the share is on VD1 so didn't add VD1 account), then created the template disk.  But it still doesn't create UPD.  Thoughts?

Comment: @JimB Apparently VDI needs session host roles (that don't install with the VDI setup).  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Yes the session host account is the key (comment 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed the role 'Remote Desktop Session Host' to test if this problem persisted with terminal sessions instead of VMs and that resolved the issue.  UVHD are now being created.